# search string and filter in listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, filtering

how can i search and filter close string in listview.

for example i have two column in my listview and both are bindable.

let say the first column named **bindlname** and second column name as "**bindfname**"

for example this is my listview record:

[image]

now if ever i type "**Y** and hit search button. it will filter **YU ZIQ and FEAGS YAPSLE**
all first letter in lastname and firstname that starts with letter "**Y**" will be filtered... another if every i will type "**UY**" it will display **UY QILUZ and UY ZKAE**

Comment: That's a requirements description. But what have you tried?

Comment: If the binding always contains strings, then you can use the String inbuilt function... String.StartsWith(SearchKey);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ICollectionView` to binding your data to `ListView` and when you press the button you can filter this data.

Sample code:

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }

    public class MainViewModel : NotificationObject
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            SearchPerson = new DelegateCommand(this.OnSearchPerson);        

            // test data
            _myDataSource.Add(new Person { Name = "John", Surname = "Blob" });
            _myDataSource.Add(new Person { Name = "Jack", Surname = "Smith" });
            _myDataSource.Add(new Person { Name = "Adam", Surname = "Jackson" });
        }

        private List<Person> _myDataSource = new List<Person>();

        private string _searchString;
        public string SearchString
        {
            get { return _searchString; }
            set { _searchString = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => SearchPerson); }
        }

        private ICollectionView _people;
        public ICollectionView People
        {
            get { return CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_myDataSource); }           
        }

        public ICommand SearchPerson { get; private set; }
        private void OnSearchPerson()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
            {
                People.Filter = (item) => { return (item as Person).Name.StartsWith(SearchString) || (item as Person).Surname.StartsWith(SearchString) ? true : false; };
            }
            else
                People.Filter = null;
        }
    }
```

XAML file:

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SearchString}" Width="150" />
            <Button Content="Search" Command="{Binding SearchPerson}" />
        </StackPanel>

        <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Surname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Surname}" />
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

[Here](http://sdrv.ms/RLZdj5) is complete example (ListViewSearch.zip).

Comment: boom! you save my day. thank you so much @kmatyaszek :) +1